# i trying to collect different info with Get-ADComputer, Get-WmiObject and Get-windowsfeature

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-wmiobject

I am trying to collect different properties from all computer listed from my AD but I can't get format to recolected querys

I run get-adcomputer query

```
$computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "SCPW*" -and ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | Select-Object -Property Name,objectClass`
```

I collect info from al computer listed in $computerlist

```
$list = foreach ($computer in $computerList) {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name }
$WFeature = foreach ($computer in $computerList) {Get-windowsfeature | Where {$_.installed -Eq $true} | Select-Object -Property Name}
$Wrole = foreach ($computer in $computerList) {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ServerFeature -Property * | select pscomputername,name }
```

Finally I try to list all info collected in a unique table with

```
%{[PSCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName' = $computer.Name
        'features'     = $WFeature.name
        'Role'    = $Wrole.name
        'list'    = $list.name
    } } | Format-table
```

but the table listed is only in one line

```
ComputerName features                                                                  Role                                                                                       list            
------------ --------                                                                  ----                                                                                       ----            
SCPWEXC0101  {File-Services, FS-FileServer, Remote-Desktop-Services, RDS-RD-Server...} {Web Server (IIS), File Services, Print and Document Services, Remote Desktop Services...} {Microsoft Ap...
```

[the table listed only in one line (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epxUZ.png)

I really will be much gratefull if somebody give me some help, I'm learning PS and I really lossed with this query. I've been running Ps 5.1

Thanks!!

Comment: You definitely do not want to use `Select-Object -Property Name` or you will lose the correlation between `$list`, `$WFeature` and `$Wrole`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put the queries inside a loop for each single computer to keep the correlation between the collected information and the computer name. Something like this should get you started:

```
$computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "SCPW*" -and ObjectClass -eq "Computer"'
$Result = 
foreach ($computer in $computerList) { 
    $CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $computer.name

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName         = $computer.Name
        WindowsFeatureList   = (Get-windowsfeature -ComputerName $computer.name | Where-Object { $_.installed } | Select-Object -Property Name) -join ', '
        W32ServerFeatureList = (Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSession -ClassName Win32_ServerFeature | Select-Object -Property Name) -join ', '
        W32ProductList       = (Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSession -ClassName Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name) -join ', '
    }
}
$Result
```

Comment: Agreed, the other alternative would be the `for` loop to combine the 3 resulting `arrays` if he needs to output 1 win feature, server feature and product per object.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon OK, but the three loops do not query remote computers. They query the local computer that many times as there are computers in the `$Computerlist`   ;-)

Comment: Yup, I meant from your code snippet, instead of using `-join` the alternative is save the 3 results in variables to then `for` loop over them.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Ah ... I see ... you're right. There is room for improvement.  ;-) That could be the next step for Alejandro.  ;-)